# Clap arg group containing arguments with different requirements and conflicts

Tags: rust, arguments, command-line-interface, clap

I am trying to write a CLI in Rust with the help of Clap and YAML. My input will require one argument (file path) and one of the flags `-s`, `-r`, or `-g`. The flags `-s` and `-r` will require one of the two flags `-t` and `-m`, but the flag `-g` conflicts with both `-t` and `-m`. I am trying to configure it so that `-g` will not be accepted if `-t` or `-m` is selected, but it disallows the use of `-s` or `-r` with either `-t` or `-m`.

How do I configure my YAML file so that I can disallow `-gt` and `-gm` but allow (and require) the use of `-t` or `-m` with `-s` or `-r`?

cli.yml:

```
name: mfm
version: "0.1.0"
author: Jonathan Marple <elpramnoj@gmail.com>
about: Media file manager written in rust.
args:
    - INPUT:
        help: Sets the input file(s) to use
        required: true
    - scrape:
        short: s
        long: scrape
        help: Scrape information on show/movie
        requires:
            - DB
    - rename:
        short: r
        long: rename
        help: Rename file(s)
        requires:
            - DB
    - generate:
        short: g
        long: generate
        help: Generate folders for file(s)
        conflicts_with:
            - tvdb
            - tmdb
    - tvdb:
        short: t
        long: tvdb
        help: Pull from tvdb
    - tmdb:
        short: m
        long: tmdb
        help: Pull from tmdb
groups:
    - CMD:
        required: true
        args:
            - scrape
            - rename
            - generate
    - DB:
        args:
            - tvdb
            - tmdb
```

I've also tried marking `DB` under `conflicts_with:` but it behaves the same way regardless.

Comment: If scrap, rename or generate can't be used at the same time, it might be easier to set them up as subcommands, and each could have it's own parameters

Comment: That's what I started out with but switched to flags for simplicity. Its not vital that I have it functioning the way I want it to yet so I may go back and delve a bit deeper into subcommands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Francois' suggestion, I switched to using subcommands. I had to write out my `-t` and `-m` flags and their `DB` group twice, once for each subcommand that uses them. I was trying to avoid that to keep my YAML file clean and less repetitive but functionality is more important.

Working YAML file:

```
name: mfm
version: "0.1.0"
author: Jonathan Marple <elpramnoj@gmail.com>
about: Media file manager written in rust.
args:
    - INPUT:
        help: Sets the input file(s) to use
        required: true
        min_values: 1
subcommands:
    - scrape:
        about: Scrape information on show/movie
        args:
            - tvdb:
                short: t
                long: tvdb
                help: Pull from tvdb
            - tmdb:
                short: m
                long: tmdb
                help: Pull from tmdb
        groups:
            - DB:
                required: true
                args:
                    - tvdb
                    - tmdb
    - rename:
        about: Rename file(s)
        args:
            - tvdb:
                short: t
                long: tvdb
                help: Pull from tvdb
            - tmdb:
                short: m
                long: tmdb
                help: Pull from tmdb
        groups:
            - DB:
                required: true
                args:
                    - tvdb
                    - tmdb
    - generate:
        about: Generate folders for file(s)
```